# Parsing user input string to UTCTime type

Tags: haskell

I'm using [opt-parse applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) to parse user input.

I'm trying to write a function that'll take a string as an input and return `UTCTime`.

`parseTime :: String -> Maybe UTCTime`

but I don't want it to fail unless the user inputs something completely off the mark.

So I pass a variable `fallbackTime` which is just reapplication of result of [`getCurrentTime`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.3/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:getCurrentTime).

So the new `parseTime` function looks like this

`parseTime :: UTCTime -> String -> Maybe UTCTime`

---

---

#### Examples

Input`2019-05-04, 12:49pm`

Parsed: `2019-05-04 12:49:29 UTC`

so left to right goes from year to month to day to hour to min to sec.

---

If there's no day half identifier (AM/PM)

Input: `2019-05-04, 12:49`

Parsed: `2019-05-04 00:49:29 UTC`

should default to `fallbackTime`'s half.

---

Now if the user doesn't give a specific year, I want it to default to `fallbackTime`'s year.

Input: `05 04, 12:49`

Parsed: `2020-05-04 00:49:29 UTC`

Input: `04, 12:49`

Parsed: `2020-05-04 00:49:29 UTC`

---

If the user doesn't input `year`, `month` or `minutes`, I want those ones default to `fallbackTime`

Input: `04, 12`

Parsed: `2020-05-04 00:49:29 UTC`

---

If the user doesn't input anything but just one number

Input: `12`

It should be considered hour and rest should be filled according to `fallbackTime`

Parsed: `2020-05-04 00:49:29 UTC`

---

I want it to fail only if the input is too long

Input: `2019 05 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12, 12:49`

or just gibberish

Input: `alpaca bob-cat regular-cat dog elephant`

---

So basically missing things should be replaced with fallback things.

So far I've found two main strategies that work -

1. Parse user input into UTCTime and then fix it.
2. Fix user input string and then try to parse it into UTCTime

---

First strategy include functions like

```
gotYear  :: String -> Bool
gotMonth :: String -> Bool
gotDay   :: String -> Bool
```

which check if the user has given enough numbers to be parsed as at least `hour` and then filling up rest using `fallbackTime`

and

second strategy splits userinput at `,` if possible, first of that tuple is fed to a function like this

```
fixupDate :: UTCTime -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
```

and the second one is fed to a similar function

```
fixupTime :: UTCTime -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
```

`Maybe` in this takes care of missing `date` is there's no `,` delimiter.

Finally it is parsed like this

`parseTimeM true defaultTimeLocale <format string> <result of parsing>`

`<result of parsing>` looks like this

```
2019-05-04 12:45
```

which is parsed using this format string

```
"%Y-%-m-%-d %l:%M"
```

---

Both of those strategies work fine but the implementations spans several lines of code and feel extremely over-engineered.

Parsing the string into tokens and parsing delimiters both are fairly straightforward, the main problem is replacing missing things with `fallbackTime`'s values.

Is there a more simple, more functional/application way of doing this?

I'm thinking something like this `pseudo-code`

```
parseTime userInputTime fallbackTime = UTCTime { userInputYear <|> fallbackYear
                                               , userInputMonth <|> fallbackMonth
                                               , ...
                                               , ...
                                               }

                where userInputYear  = getUserInputYear  userInputTime :: Maybe Year
                      userInputMonth = getUserInputMonth userInputTime :: Maybe Month 
                      ...
                      ...
                      fallbackYear   = getYear  fallbackTime  :: Maybe Year
                      fallbackMonth  = getMonth fallbackTime  :: Maybe Month
```

or should I stick with one of those strategies and try to make the code more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one general comment, that you are biting off a large chunk of functionality with this approach, and, as you suggested, it is greatly over-engineered.

1. You should not provide the seconds value when it is not present in the source. If seconds is not present in the source, its value is zero.
2. Without an AM/PM indicator, `12:49` should be `12:49:00`. Don't set the hour field to zero.
3. When the year is missing, you will run afoul very quickly of people who use the American-style day-then-month notation.
4. Similarly, do not try to guess the month. The hour should default to `00` if not present, as you would for minutes and seconds.
5. One number, by itself, is so lacking in context that you cannot reasonably assume its significance. Stay away from this.

You are greatly over-engineering something that is fraught with pitfalls. Any code solution you attempt will necessarily be long and convoluted.

Also, if you need half-a-page of documentation to explain your choices to the user of your system, you are engineering the wrong end of the problem.